# Catching exceptions when using <int-xml:validating-filter>

Tags: spring, exception, error-handling, spring-integration

I am pulling data from queue and then validating the input payload using **int-xml:validating-filter**.  I have set **throw-exception-on-rejection="true"** so that exception is thrown.

I need to get hold of the exception message(validation errors) as well as the input payload.  Could you please suggest the options available to capture this data?

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter   id="jmsIn"    
destination="requestQueue" channel="orderChannel"/> 

<int-xml:validating-filter id="validatingFilter"
    input-channel="orderChannel"
    output-channel="validOutputChannel"
    discard-channel="errOutputChannel"                             
    schema-type="xml-schema"
    throw-exception-on-rejection="true"         
    schema-location="OrderProcessing/order.xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You concern isn't clear, if you can catch that exception.

The code in the `XmlValidatingMessageSelector` looks like:

```
if (this.throwExceptionOnRejection) {
    throw new MessageRejectedException(message, "Message was rejected due to XML Validation errors",
            new AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException(
                Arrays.<Throwable>asList(validationExceptions)));
}
```

So, that `MessageRejectedException` has the desired `message` as a cause for validation failure. And all the validation errors are represent in the `AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException` `cause` of that `MessageRejectedException`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Artem Bilan

Comment: I was looking at options for catching the exception in <int-xml:validating-filter>.   I was assuming that <int-xml:validating-filter> would provide the exception in the discard-channel or output-channel. Now I understand that since the exception is thrown the caller has to handle it.

In my particular case, I added error channel in <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter> and now I am able to capture the validation error message as well the actual payload from it.